# Im not able to connect Tablet to server in PC (LAN)

Tags: eclipse, jboss, port, wildfly, tablet

I am using Eclipse WebPlugin that have Jboos servers inside. Muy aplication its deployed inside (Jboss Wildfly- external server) and runs on localhost:8180/foldername

Now I want to conect with my tablet to this server that its runing on my Pc but refuse the connection.

I have tried to open the firewall ports from 8000 to 8200 and I have changed the standalone.xml to allow all IP to conect the server setting the address to 0

```
<interface name="public">
            <inet-address value="${jboss.bind.address:0.0.0.0}"/>
        </interface>
```

But nothing works. here the order of the thing that I want to do:

1. deploy project on Eclipse Jboss -> run in
       localhost:8180/foldername
2. use the tablet browser to acced to my
           PC -> 196.xxx.xxx.xx:8180/foldername

Both computer are in the same subred. some one know what happend or what can i do connect. 
Thanks to all

Comment: did you tell jboss to bind port 8180?

Comment: Is 196.xxx.xxx.xx the right address?

Comment: I havent binded the port, but its supossed that the port its the same in both cases. And yes, the IP its taken from the IPconfig in my  Pc